# How do I change Z offset in Blender 2.8?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, uv, workflow, customization

I'm trying to get an object to show up in front of another. Where is the Z offset, and am I able to keyframe the value?

Comment: Im sorry, could you make your question more clear?

Comment: I want to be able to have an object appear in front of another, like the old X-ray feature you could use in the viewport, without using more than one collection. I've hear you can do this using Z offset, but I've never found anything explaining where Z offset is in the endless menus, or how to use it.

Comment: Could you please [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/172923/edit) the extra details commented under answer below, including image, video link, and blend file  into question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 3 options;

1. Make whatever is in front of the object semi-transparent.
2. Render the object, then render what is in front of it (each perhaps on their own render layer), then composite the two renders in the compositer.
3. Move the object closer to the camera than the object that is obscuring it.

As far as I know, there is no "z-offset" setting for an object in blender.

### Edit for followup comments

Given your example, I've come up with the following proof of concept;

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have attached the .blend file;

[image]

### Explanation

First, forgive my model, it was a quick mock-up. By the time you sent your blend, I was almost ready to post :)

So, what I've done here is created a series of spheres, nested inside each other;

[image]

Then, I flipped them inside out (so to speak - I've actually just flipped the normal of all the faces by going into edit mode, selecting everything, searching for "flip normals", and clicking that option). This allows you to see all the spheres, despite being inside each other.

Note: This should be visible by default in Material Preview and Render modes, but if you want to see it in Solid mode, you'll need to turn on backface culling specifically for that mode;

[image]

[image]

Now, as for the shading, I set up the following node structure;

[image]

Effectively, what this does is flat shades the object (so you don't have the odd, inverted, shaded spheres).

To note, this is a default ColorRamp;

[image]

I only wanted the one color (no shading, no variation), so I completely deleted the first slider. Then I changed the color to the desired value.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try 2 as it seems like it'll do what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: It doesn't work. If it did work, it probably wouldn't be able to be keyframed.

Comment: As in, at one point it's hidden, and at another point it's not? And then perhaps re-hidden? It may be worth while for you to explain your end goal in less general terms.

Comment: Pictures say a thousand words, so I'll use those instead. If you look at the engines, when they're viewed from the rear, the particles go behind one another. If Z offset works like I think it does, then I think that every object in the scene should just have an increasingly lower Z offset the closer they are to the camera, then the particles get the 3 lowest Z offset values the closer they are to the engine so that only the engine particles appear in front of each other without breaking the scene. https://imgur.com/a/6ODfoSQ

Comment: I feel like the term "particles" is at issue here. Particle systems in Blender are a very specific thing, which I don't see in use here. Do you mean the output of the engines? Further, do you mean that from whatever angle you see the engine output, you'd like it to look like successively larger circles, from the inside out, decreasing in brightness (as in your first image)?

Comment: Let's look at that I'm trying to recreate: https://youtu.be/GzEj4Gq7fT4     The engine exhaust doesn't break when looked at from the rear, but that's what happens to me. Perhaps I'm using a method to recreate the visuals that doesn't work very well?

Comment: Here's the .blend file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xjeakt9jvdu2vir/FEII.blend?dl=0

Comment: Ah ha, exactly as I thought. I've already been working on an example, stand by...

Comment: Updated answer with basics, writing up explanation...

Comment: Updated answer will full write up so you can reproduce this later, outside of my file

Comment: Can also scale faces by -1 in edit mode to flip normals.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem :) If this is the method you choose to employ, please select it as the Accepted Answer ✔️

Comment: batFINGER: Yes, that's a way. I normally (HA) don't like to suggest it, because you'll get different results depending on whether you are in Object or Edit mode (and whether or not you apply the transformation)